# Is AngularJS's factory the same as a factory pattern?

Tags: angularjs, design-patterns

Yesterday, I heard a colleague state that the factory in angular is not the same as the factory pattern. I'm curious about if this is a valid statement and why.

Normally factories will create you an instance of an object. From looking at our code, it looks like the factory is a wrapper or object that can be called for the related web services as well, so GET, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE. There are some instances, where this varies, however for the most part, it looks like something that helps interact with the related web services.

Having a factory that returns objects just based on "GET" seems like it would align more with a traditional factory pattern, but the fact that we deal with the other verbs, makes me think that is where things deviate from the pattern.

Can someone confirm if this is the standard way to use angular factories and if so, if my intuition/thoughts are correct, or if I'm missing something?

**Update**

There as a request to provide code as to what I'm talking about. I did some googling for angular factory examples, to see if others are doing similar stuff as to what I'm seeing at my work. Which I found the following example: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/using-an-angularjs-factory-to-interact-with-a-restful-service

When you look at the example, you'll notice that the "dataFactory" does not just have a GET, it has other HTTP verbs too. Is this bad practice from the user base, or is it the standard way to use it and the factory is different from the design pattern?

Comment: You should really clarify, with code, what you mean by AngularJS factory.

Comment: like referencing `module().factory`? pretty sure this is a common concept

Comment: Yes, but it has absolutely nothing to do with HTTP, GET, PUT, etc. So it's quite hard to understand what you're asking. A factory is just a function whose responsibility is to create a service instance. Nothing more than that.

Comment: @JBNizet, that was my understanding and believe you've confirmed it. Sounds to me like they've been using things improperly.

Answer (score 1):

Factory is a recipe of Provider in Angular and a form of Factory pattern, which is simply a process of one object takes responsibility to create other objects.

The example you referred is also an implementation of Factory pattern though not ideal, dataFactory creates and returns a proxy kind object which will be used in another consuming class to perform CRUD operations. Don't confuse it with HTTP verbs which are nothing to do with Factory pattern. In other words, factory class can return an object that can contain any kind of operations.

An ideal way to implement factory class:

```
function Bird(type) {
    this.type = type; 
    //constructor logic
    this.fly= function () {
        //other business logic
    };
}
//Below class is a factory which creates object for requested Bird type
function BirdFactory() {     
    this.create = function(type) {
        return new Bird(type);
    };
}
```

Hope this clarifies.